# Mask lots of missing Data in tricontourf

Tags: matplotlib, masking

[image]
I have a relatively large dataset which contains data for a whole year. I did so by concatenating all the dataframes for each doy to come up with this huge dataset however on some of the days there is no data available so there are large gaps in the data. I only want to plot the real data and mask or white out the missing data. I tried to resample the data to hourly but when i do this i get an *"Error in qhull Delaunay triangulation calculation: input inconsistency (exitcode=1)"*
So at first i tried to drop the NAN the problem is tricontourf ended up filling the missing data instead of ignoring it or masking it. So i came up with the solution below but it is only masking part of the points and filling the other half with artifacts.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as mp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.tri as tri
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
dy=devstns[0]
dy=dy.resample("H",base=1).mean()
dy["date"]=dy.index
dy["doy"] = dy["date"].apply(lambda x: x.timetuple().tm_yday)
dy =dy.fillna(0)
x=dy.doy.values
y=dy.UT.values[![enter image description here][1]][1]
z=dy.TEC.values
bad = np.ma.masked_invalid(z)
isbad=np.equal(z,0)
triang = tri.Triangulation(x, y)
mask = np.any(np.where(isbad[triang.triangles], True, False), axis=1)
triang.set_mask(mask)
colplt = ax.tricontourf(triang, z)
```

Here is a data sample

|pctDev  |  doy  | deltaTEC   |    QTEC |   year  |      TEC     |    UT
date
2018-08-01 00:00:00         NaN    NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN        NaN        NaN
2018-08-01 01:00:00         NaN    NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN        NaN        NaN
2018-08-01 02:00:00         NaN    NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN        NaN        NaN
2018-08-01 03:00:00         NaN    NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN        NaN        NaN
2018-08-01 04:00:00         NaN    NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN        NaN        NaN
2018-08-01 05:00:00         NaN    NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN        NaN        NaN
2018-08-01 06:00:00         NaN    NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN        NaN        NaN
2018-08-01 07:00:00         NaN    NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN        NaN        NaN
2018-08-01 08:00:00         NaN    NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN        NaN        NaN
2018-08-01 09:00:00         NaN    NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN        NaN        NaN
2018-08-01 10:00:00         NaN    NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN        NaN        NaN
2018-08-01 11:00:00         NaN    NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN        NaN        NaN

2018-08-01 21:00:00         NaN    NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN        NaN        NaN
2018-08-01 22:00:00         NaN    NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN        NaN        NaN
2018-08-01 23:00:00         NaN    NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN        NaN        NaN
2018-08-02 00:00:00         NaN    NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN        NaN        NaN
2018-08-02 01:00:00         NaN    NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN        NaN        NaN
2018-08-02 02:00:00         NaN    NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN        NaN        NaN
2018-08-02 03:00:00         NaN    NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN        NaN        NaN
2018-08-02 04:00:00         NaN    NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN        NaN        NaN
2018-08-02 05:00:00         NaN    NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN        NaN        NaN
2018-08-02 06:00:00         NaN    NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN        NaN        NaN
2018-08-02 07:00:00         NaN    NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN        NaN        NaN
2018-08-02 08:00:00         NaN    NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN             NaN        NaN

2018-08-05 14:00:00         NaN    NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN        NaN        NaN
2018-08-05 15:00:00         NaN    NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN        NaN        NaN
2018-08-05 16:00:00         NaN    NaN        NaN        NaN     NaN        NaN        NaN

2018-08-15 00:00:00  -33.568720  227.0  -2.578583   7.558583  2018.0   4.980000   0.491667
2018-08-15 01:00:00  -21.027371  227.0  -1.216333   5.755833  2018.0   4.539500   1.491667
2018-08-15 02:00:00  -11.645713  227.0  -0.593917   5.052917  2018.0   4.459000   2.491667
2018-08-15 03:00:00  -11.743647  227.0  -0.461083   3.936250  2018.0   3.475167   3.491667
2018-08-15 04:00:00   -5.666851  227.0  -0.184583   3.155417  2018.0   2.970833   4.491667
2018-08-15 05:00:00   -5.690906  227.0  -0.154583   2.702417  2018.0   2.547833   5.491667
2018-08-15 06:00:00  -16.918020  227.0  -0.469583   2.766583  2018.0   2.297000   6.491667
2018-08-15 07:00:00   -2.511416  227.0  -0.061917   2.550750  2018.0   2.488833   7.491667

Comment: If your data is hourly, I'd shape as a (m, n) sized matrix where m is the number of hours (24) and n is the number of days.  They you can just use `contourf` and/or `pcolormesh`.  Whether they will exactly mask things the way you want depends a bit on your gaps, but it will be a lot easier than trying to do a triangulation over gaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tricontourf apparently does not accept NAN for the x and y arrays so I filled in the missing x values just as i did for the Julian day which is probably why it was masking only halfway. In my case I   used the timetuple to fill in missing julian day and time. I think this allows the triangulation to find the indices where z in Nan(set to zero) so as to mask.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as mp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.tri as tri
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
dy=devstns[0]
dy=dy.resample("H",base=1).mean()
dy["date"]=dy.index
dy["doy"] = dy["date"].apply(lambda x: x.timetuple().tm_yday)
dy["HH"] = dy["date"].apply(lambda x: x.timetuple().tm_hour)

dy =dy.fillna(0)
x=dy.doy.values
y=dy.UT.values
z=dy.TEC.values

isbad=np.equal(z,0)
triang = tri.Triangulation(x, y)
mask = np.any(np.where(isbad[triang.triangles], True, False), axis=1)
triang.set_mask(mask)
colplt = ax.tricontourf(triang, z)
```